# Emplace and insert in unordered_map in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'm struggling to do the most basic thing with an unordered_map in c++ using VS2010: inserting something.

```
unordered_map<string, string> cats;
//cats.insert("Adam", "Streak");
//cats.emplace("Kyra", "Shadow");
```

I'm sure I'm making a very simple mistake, but I have spent two hours now trying to figure it out to to avail.  Both the commented lines above give errors when uncommented.

When `cats.insert("Adam", "Streak");` is uncommented, the error is:

> Error 1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional

When `cats.emplace("Kyra", "Shadow");` is uncommented, the error is:

> Error 1   error C2780: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Hash<_Traits>::emplace(_Valty &&)' : expects 1 arguments - 2 provided

I am quite confused, as there are several examples across the internet using this exact syntax.  For example, cplusplus.com [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/emplace/).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your compiler's old and only partially supports C++11... it's an easy google to find details, but more productive to upgrade if you can.

Comment: Exact sintax, you say? [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/)

Answer (score 3):

Both functions accept `std::pair<A,B>` `make_pair` is the easiest way to make a pair.

```
cats.insert(std::make_pair("Adam", "Streak"));
cats.emplace(std::make_pair("Kyra", "Shadow"));
```

or

```
cats.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("Adam", "Streak"));
```

http://ideone.com/43GqyB

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error C2678 when doing it this way.  At this point I'm leaning toward Visual Studio being very broken.

Comment: Which version are you using tho? I'm using VS 2015 and it works perfectly fine. I've also added an ideone.com link and it works there too.

Comment: Thanks Jose.  I didn't realize unordered_map was introduced in c++11.  After upgrading to VS2015 it works as expected.